# why SDWebImageDownloaderOperation begins background task and ends it soon after that

Tags: sdwebimage

The download operation begins a background task in start method. But the task is ended at the end of the start method.

Why not keep the background task util the download task finishing?

[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.m](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.m#L217)

```
- (void)start { 
   ...
   self.backgroundTaskId = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ // line: 137
   ...
   [app endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskId]; // line: 217
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please include your code within the question, so that it is easy to read.

Comment: The asynchronous download task is resume in start method, but the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method seems to be useless here